# Existing data can not be edited in django models

Tags: python, django, django-models, edit

After saving the filed , i want to make the field non editable, how i can do that.

```
end_run = models.PositiveIntegerField(
    null=True, blank=True, help_text=_("Can be enter value Onece")
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the required [method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#editable)

```
end_run = models.PositiveIntegerField(
    null=True, 
    blank=True, 
    help_text=_("Can be enter value Onece"),
    editable=False
)
```

Comment: Hi, With that code i will not be able to save any value , after saving value , it can not be unchanged.@jsrb